# Energy stored in a battery?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, energy, power

I want to calculate the energy lost from a battery to heat, and the energy stored in a battery. Are these formula's correct?

$ E_b$ = $I$$V$ x $t$

$ E_H$ = $I$$R$$^2$ x $t$

$E_b$ = energy stored in the battery.

$E_H$ = energy lost to heat.

$t$ = time.

Comment: $E_H=I^2 Rt$. You should consider efficiency of the charging process as well.

Comment: What will calculate the energy stored? ... I will after understanding this step first.

Comment: Do you want to know how much it stores or how much it can give? Amount stored could be calculated using nernst equation for alkaline batteries, how much a battery can give would be extremely difficult in my opinion!

Comment: Both if possible, but if you can explain in an answer as why its difficult to know how much it could give out would be useful.